# Derivatives Affecting the Shape of a Graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)= x^4 - 50x^2 + 4$

Okay, so I get that my first step is to find the Critical Points.

Here is what I have for that:

$f'(x)= 4x(x - 5)(x + 5)=0$

,so my Critical Points are -5,0,5.

I am having trouble with the interval chart. I may need someone to really dumb this down for me as I'm probably over analyzing this. I'm searching for where it increases at, decreases at, the absolute min and max, the inflection point, and where the concave up and down takes place.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have THREE roots, so you will have   FOUR intervals.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)=4x(x-5)(x+5)$. Your critical points are correct: $-5,0,5$. When $x<-5$, $x$ is $---$, when $-5<x<0$, $+++$, when $0<x<5$, $x$ is $---$, when $x>5$, $x$ is$+++$.You get these by plugging in values on the intervals. The function decreases when $f'(x)<0$, and increases when $f'(x)>0$. There's a relative max when the sign changes from $+++$ to $---$. There's a relative min when the sign changes from $---$ to $+++$. The function is concave up when $f''(x)<0$, and concave down when $f''(x)>0$. It has a inflection point when $f''(x)$ changes it's sign.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, if you like the answer accept it/upvote it so people know it's answered.

Answer (score 0):

Find derivative of function first, and check the critical points.

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^4-50 x^2+4) = 4x(x^2-25)=4x(x-5)(x+5)$

The critical points are $x=-5,0,5$, and $f(-5) = -621$, $f(0) = 4$, $f(5) = -621$.

$f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty , -5)$; $f$ is increasing on $(-5,0)$; $f$ is decreasing on $(0,5)$; $f$ is increasing on $(5,+\infty)$.

$f^{\prime\prime} (x) = (4x^3-100x)^\prime = 12x^2-100 = 12 ( x - \sqrt{\frac{25}{3}}) ( x + \sqrt{\frac{25}{3}})$. The inflection points are when $f^{\prime\prime}$ changes its sign. They are at $x = \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and $x = -\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{3}$.